# SMPS design formulas confusion

Tags: voltage, current, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, frequency

I was working on the SMPS but I have having trouble in getting a propper method to follow before designing an SMPS. I followed a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B16iDPeH0EY&list=PLgsKzaoLQUjo8s4G784yFDx2sm23-cQ89&index=3) series but I didn't know where all those formulas came from as I couldn't find them in any other relevant source. Can anyone help in getting some links regarding the design of an SMPS with formulas if required? One such image is shown below:
[image]

Comment: Most SMPS chips have documentation that contains the formulas you need to design with the chip. Some chips just give the formulas to you without deriving where they come from as you don't need that to design with the chip. Some chips go for extra and also derive them for you. The formulas may not look equal as they might be in slightly different form. Have you tried searching for yourself first, like putting "smps design" into your favourite web search engine?

Comment: Right. I'll take the documentation from the application notes of the ICs and their datasheets. It means the formulas vary,depending on the control IC.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to use this classic induction equation:

$$V = L\times \frac{I}{T_{ON}} $$

And used energy stored in the inductor

$$E = \frac{1}{2} L I^2$$

$$E = \frac{1}{2} L \: \left(T_{ON} \: \frac{V}{L}\right)^2 = \frac{(V \times T_{ON})^2}{2L}$$

We solve for \$L\$:

$$L = \frac{(V \times T_{ON})^2}{2 E}$$

And the energy is equal to \$P*T\$ thus:

$$L = \frac{(V \times T_{ON})^2}{2 P \times T}$$

We have \$2\$ instead of \$2.5\$ because I assume 100% power efficiency.

If we assume 80% power efficiency we will get \$ 2 * \frac{P}{0.8} = 2.5P\$.